# Can an iPhone act as an audio source to a Mac?

Tags: iphone, mac, audio, bluetooth, recording

Is there a way to pull the audio from an iphone phone call to a mac either via bluetooth or USB? In other words, use the mac and a cellular phone hybrid?  I'd like to be able to record a phone call or voice mail to the mac.

I realize i could do this many other ways including using an true phone hybrid, but I'd like to keep the amount of equipment i have to take when traveling.

I'm sure i could also use a TRRS Y cable from the headphone/mic jack into my mac, but i'd also like to keep it in the digital realm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it, but you would require some professional paid apps for it like [blue phone elite](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/16070/bluephoneelite) or [phone amego](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phone-amego/id405497904?mt=12).